# Binding List to TabControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

```
enter code here
    <DockPanel>
        <TabControl Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Configurations}">
            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AlgorithmActivityName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding **Configuration** }"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </DockPanel>
```

Hey here is my xaml i want to bind de content of each TabControl item to a Property of the Configurations class. But at this point the datacontext is not available anymore. Can anyone help please

Comment: Seems like you need some RelativeSource Binding

Comment: The datacontext should still be available the way you have it written. To test this, replace your Textblock binding to be `"{Binding AlgorithmActivityName}"` to prove whether or not the datacontext is still available. If it works, then your datacontext is still available. If it doesn't work, then you are correct.